# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java

I can visit mysql by the command line and I have seen several questions about this,but it doesn't work.  
I have tried:

> 1.mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'password' with grant option;   
>   2.Create a new user;   
>   3.modify the password;

This is my users' info.

> mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user;

```
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+  
| user | host      | password                                  |  
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+  
| root | localhost | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |  
| root | 127.0.0.1 | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |  
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

```html
/* 15 */     String driver = "";
/* 16 */     String url = "";
/* 17 */     driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
/* 18 */     url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?characterEncoding=utf-8";
/* 19 */     Connection con = null;
/* 20 */     String user = "root";
/* 21 */     String pwd = "root";
/*    */     try {
/*    */       try {
/* 25 */         Class.forName(driver);
/*    */       } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
/* 27 */         ex.printStackTrace();
/*    */       }
   System.out.println("url:"+url+" user="+user+" pwd="+pwd);
/* 29 */       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
/*    */     } catch (SQLException ex) {
/* 31 */       ex.printStackTrace();
/*    */     }
```

Comment: Not really sure but why do you have 3 strings "pwd" ? are you able to login with user name root and password root?

Comment: yes,sorry,I forgot to del the useless 'PWD'..

Comment: The difference between your shell attempt and your code attempt is that the code tries to connect directly to a database while in the shell you only connect to MySQL and you don't do anything more. Can you login as root/root and 'use demo' from the shell?

Comment: Can you log in to "demo" as root using the MySQL command line tool?

Comment: @Gimby @P yes,i can handle 'demo'.

Comment: And in the MySQL instance manager there is only one instance? The server is not going to lie to you, so there must be some simple reason why you get different results when connecting through different paths.

Comment: Try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 or your machine IP once and try. Please update the correct code that you are using, without the "useless 'PWD'".

Comment: @RajarshiGoswami   127 and the machine IP I have tried,the same result. The question has been updated.Both username and password are 'root'.

Comment: @Gimby There is several databases in the MySQL.I tried to use another database instead of 'demo',the same result. Isn't there any questions in MySQL configs?

Comment: Can you try once by by providing an empty string as password or without providing a password

Comment: Instances are not databases (which exist within one instance) but rather different MySQL installations. you might have MySQL 5.1 and MySQL 5.6 installed at the same time for example.

Comment: @Gimby understand,i have only one:MySQL5.7

Comment: @RajarshiGoswami yes,i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG,sorry,i have found my question.The key is that there are two same projects in the webapps.The wrong log is reported by the first project,not the current project.